# Joins Query not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, inner-join, mariadb

```
public function getQuestions($params = "",$page= "all", $count=false){
$this->db->query('SELECT  questions.questions_id, questions.question_description,
        questions.question_explanation, questions.created_date,
        questions.updated_date, questions.is_active,
        diffLevels.difficulty_levels_title
    FROM  '.TBL_QUESTION.' as questions
    INNER JOIN  '.TBL_DIFFICULTY_LEVELS.' as diffLevels
           ON questions.fk_difficulty_levels_id = diffLevels.preference
    WHERE  questions.is_active=1');
            $Q = $this->db->get();
            if ($Q->num_rows() > 0) { 
                foreach ($Q->result() as $row) { 
                    $data[] = $row; 
                } 
            } 
            $Q->free_result(); 
            return $data;

        }
```

This is my Query..and I did few many tweaks but it wont work..waiting for possible solutions? Thanks

Comment: if you try to run this in `'SELECT questions.questions_id,questions.question_description,questions.question_explanation,questions.created_date,questions.updated_date,questions.is_active,diffLevels.difficulty_levels_title FROM '.TBL_QUESTION.' as questions INNER JOIN '.TBL_DIFFICULTY_LEVELS.' as diffLevels ON questions.fk_difficulty_levels_id = diffLevels.preference WHERE questions.is_active=1'` in sql command than what error you get?

Comment: whats is an error?

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'questions.questions_id,questions.question_description,questions.question_explana' at line 1

questions.questions_id,questions.question_description,questions.question_explanation,questions.created_date,questions.updated_date,questionFilename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ias2\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: sometimes the following error also occuring,<br> A Database Error Occurred

**Error Number: 1096**

No tables used

`SELECT *`

_Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ias2\system\database\DB_driver.php_

Line Number: 330

Comment: @silambarasanR.D : Have you checked whether you are getting correct values of the variables that you have used for table names- `TBL_QUESTION` and `TBL_DIFFICULTY_LEVELS` ? From where you are setting values for this two variables ?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Yea I checked it...Its not a problem..Its just defined with table names..

Comment: @silambarasanR.D: If they are defined with table names, try using table-names directly in query instead of appending the variables and share the error message.

Comment: shouldn't you have `->result_array();` at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
$this->db->select('
        questions.questions_id,
        questions.question_description,
        questions.question_explanation,
        questions.created_date,
        questions.updated_date,
        questions.is_active,
        diffLevels.difficulty_levels_title 
        ');
        $this->db->from("questions");
        $this->db->join("diffLevels",'questions.fk_difficulty_levels_id = diffLevels.preference' , 'inner');
        $this->db->where("questions.is_active",1);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        $data=$query->result_array(); 
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        //echo "<hr/>";
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($query);
        //exit;
```

I have directly used table name as "questions" and "diffLevels",Please change accordingly.

Comment: I changed Table names and tried it...It shows like this `Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on array in D:\xampp\htdocs\ias2\application\controllers\admin\questions.php on line 267`

Comment: @silambarasanR.D i have made changes in the code ,kindly check that and please tell what output you are getting.It will also print query in Output,just copy the query and directly run in the Php my admin.